# How to join tables from multiple dbcontexts in one ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

So I've got two dbcontexts, to get data from various tables and I want to join them in a ViewModel. I know I should probably use .Join(), but I wondered if something like this was also possible:

My Controller:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly NAV_FS_DBContext _navContext;
    private readonly DostebaPpsContext _baseDataContext;

    public HomeController(NAV_FS_DBContext navContext, DostebaPpsContext baseDataContext)
    {
        _navContext = navContext;
        _baseDataContext = baseDataContext;
    }

    // GET: Home
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<SpeweSalesLine> speweSalesList = await _navContext.SpeweSalesLines.ToListAsync();
        List<SpeweProdOrderLine> spewePoList = await _navContext.SpeweProdOrderLines.ToListAsync();
        List<Variable> baseDataList = await _baseDataContext.Variables.ToListAsync();
        List<PoItemViewModel> poItems = await _navContext.SpeweProductionOrder
            .Select(x => new PoItemViewModel
            {
                Status = x.Status,
                PONr = x.No,
                ItemNr = x.SourceNo,
                FormType = x.Description,
                Quantity = x.Quantity,
                StartingDate = x.StartingDate,
                EndingDate = x.EndingDate,
                ShipmentDate = speweSalesList.Where(y => y.No == x.No).Select(y => y.ShipmentDate).FirstOrDefault(),
                Priority = spewePoList.Where(y => y.ProdOrderNo == x.No).Select(y => y.Priority).FirstOrDefault(),
                Molds = baseDataList.Where(y => y.SourceNo == x.SourceNo).Select(y => y.MoldPerDay).FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToListAsync();

        return View(poItems);
    }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```cs
public class PoItemViewModel
{
    public string? ItemNr { get; set; }
    public int? Status { get; set; }
    public string? FormType { get; set; }
    public decimal? Quantity { get; set; }
    public int? Molds { get; set; }
    public decimal? Days { get; set; }
    public string? PONr { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartingDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndingDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ShipmentDate { get; set; }
    public int? Priority { get; set; }
}
```

NAV_FS_DBContext:

```cs
public partial class NAV_FS_DBContext : DbContext
{
    public NAV_FS_DBContext()
    {
    }

    public NAV_FS_DBContext(DbContextOptions<NAV_FS_DBContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<SpeweItem> SpeweItem { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SpeweProductionOrder> SpeweProductionOrder { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<SpeweItemLedgerEntry> SpeweItemLedgerEntries { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<SpeweSalesLine> SpeweSalesLines { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<SpeweValueEntry> SpeweValueEntries { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SpeweProdOrderLine> SpeweProdOrderLines { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Name=ConnectionStrings:CS2");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.UseCollation("Latin1_General_100_CI_AS");

        modelBuilder.Entity<SpeweItem>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.No).HasName("SPEWE$Item$0");

            entity.ToTable("SPEWE$Item", "dbo");
            //etc...
            });
            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

SpeweProductionOrder Model (from dbcontext):

```cs
public partial class SpeweProductionOrder
{
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; } = null!;

    public int Status { get; set; }

    public string No { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Description { get; set; } = null!;

    public string SearchDescription { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Description2 { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastDateModified { get; set; }

    public int SourceType { get; set; }

    public string SourceNo { get; set; } = null!;

    public string RoutingNo { get; set; } = null!;

    public string InventoryPostingGroup { get; set; } = null!;

    public string GenProdPostingGroup { get; set; } = null!;

    public string GenBusPostingGroup { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateTime StartingTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartingDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndingTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndingDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime FinishedDate { get; set; }

    public byte Blocked { get; set; }

    public string ShortcutDimension1Code { get; set; } = null!;

    public string ShortcutDimension2Code { get; set; } = null!;

    public string LocationCode { get; set; } = null!;

    public string BinCode { get; set; } = null!;

    public string ReplanRefNo { get; set; } = null!;

    public int ReplanRefStatus { get; set; }

    public int LowLevelCode { get; set; }

    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal UnitCost { get; set; }

    public decimal CostAmount { get; set; }

    public string NoSeries { get; set; } = null!;

    public string PlannedOrderNo { get; set; } = null!;

    public string FirmPlannedOrderNo { get; set; } = null!;

    public string SimulatedOrderNo { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateTime StartingDateTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndingDateTime { get; set; }

    public int DimensionSetId { get; set; }

    //etc...
}
```

SpeweSalesLine Model (from dbcontext):

```cs
public partial class SpeweSalesLine
{
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; } = null!;

    public int DocumentType { get; set; }

    public string DocumentNo { get; set; } = null!;

    public int LineNo { get; set; }

    public string SellToCustomerNo { get; set; } = null!;

    public int Type { get; set; }

    public string No { get; set; } = null!;

    public string LocationCode { get; set; } = null!;

    public string PostingGroup { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateTime ShipmentDate { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Description2 { get; set; } = null!;

    public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; } = null!;

    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal OutstandingQuantity { get; set; }

    public decimal QtyToInvoice { get; set; }

    public decimal QtyToShip { get; set; }

    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public decimal UnitCostLcy { get; set; }

    public decimal Vat { get; set; }

    public decimal LineDiscount { get; set; }

    public decimal LineDiscountAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public decimal AmountIncludingVat { get; set; }

    public byte AllowInvoiceDisc { get; set; }

    public decimal GrossWeight { get; set; }

    public decimal NetWeight { get; set; }

    public decimal UnitsPerParcel { get; set; }

    public decimal UnitVolume { get; set; }

    public int ApplToItemEntry { get; set; }

    public string ShortcutDimension1Code { get; set; } = null!;

    public string ShortcutDimension2Code { get; set; } = null!;

    public string CustomerPriceGroup { get; set; } = null!;

    public string JobNo { get; set; } = null!;

    public string WorkTypeCode { get; set; } = null!;

    public byte RecalculateInvoiceDisc { get; set; }

    public decimal OutstandingAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal QtyShippedNotInvoiced { get; set; }

    public decimal ShippedNotInvoiced { get; set; }

    public decimal QuantityShipped { get; set; }

    public decimal QuantityInvoiced { get; set; }

    public string ShipmentNo { get; set; } = null!;

    public int ShipmentLineNo { get; set; }

    public decimal Profit { get; set; }

    public string BillToCustomerNo { get; set; } = null!;

    public decimal InvDiscountAmount { get; set; }

    public string PurchaseOrderNo { get; set; } = null!;

    public int PurchOrderLineNo { get; set; }

    public byte DropShipment { get; set; }

    public string GenBusPostingGroup { get; set; } = null!;

    public string GenProdPostingGroup { get; set; } = null!;

    public int VatCalculationType { get; set; }

    public string TransactionType { get; set; } = null!;

    public string TransportMethod { get; set; } = null!;

    public int AttachedToLineNo { get; set; }

    public string ExitPoint { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Area { get; set; } = null!;

    public string TransactionSpecification { get; set; } = null!;

    public string TaxCategory { get; set; } = null!;

    public string TaxAreaCode { get; set; } = null!;

    public byte TaxLiable { get; set; }

    public string TaxGroupCode { get; set; } = null!;

    public string VatClauseCode { get; set; } = null!;

    public string VatBusPostingGroup { get; set; } = null!;

    public string VatProdPostingGroup { get; set; } = null!;

    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; } = null!;

    public decimal OutstandingAmountLcy { get; set; }

    public decimal ShippedNotInvoicedLcy { get; set; }

    public int Reserve { get; set; }

    public string BlanketOrderNo { get; set; } = null!;

    public int BlanketOrderLineNo { get; set; }

    public decimal VatBaseAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal UnitCost { get; set; }

    public byte SystemCreatedEntry { get; set; }

    public decimal LineAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal VatDifference { get; set; }

    public decimal InvDiscAmountToInvoice { get; set; }

    public string VatIdentifier { get; set; } = null!;

    public int IcPartnerRefType { get; set; }

    public string IcPartnerReference { get; set; } = null!;

    public decimal Prepayment { get; set; }

    public decimal PrepmtLineAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal PrepmtAmtInv { get; set; }

    public decimal PrepmtAmtInclVat { get; set; }

    public decimal PrepaymentAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal PrepmtVatBaseAmt { get; set; }

    public decimal PrepaymentVat { get; set; }

    public int PrepmtVatCalcType { get; set; }

    public string PrepaymentVatIdentifier { get; set; } = null!;

    public string PrepaymentTaxAreaCode { get; set; } = null!;

    public byte PrepaymentTaxLiable { get; set; }

    public string PrepaymentTaxGroupCode { get; set; } = null!;

    public decimal PrepmtAmtToDeduct { get; set; }

    public decimal PrepmtAmtDeducted { get; set; }

    public byte PrepaymentLine { get; set; }

    public decimal PrepmtAmountInvInclVat { get; set; }

    public decimal PrepmtAmountInvLcy { get; set; }

    public string IcPartnerCode { get; set; } = null!;

    public decimal PrepmtVatAmountInvLcy { get; set; }

    public decimal PrepaymentVatDifference { get; set; }

    public decimal PrepmtVatDiffToDeduct { get; set; }

    public decimal PrepmtVatDiffDeducted { get; set; }

    public int DimensionSetId { get; set; }

    public decimal QtyToAssembleToOrder { get; set; }

    public decimal QtyToAsmToOrderBase { get; set; }

    public string JobTaskNo { get; set; } = null!;

    public int JobContractEntryNo { get; set; }

    public string DeferralCode { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateTime ReturnsDeferralStartDate { get; set; }

    //etc...
}
```

Variable Model (from dbcontext)

```cs
public partial class Variable
{
    public string SourceNo { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Type { get; set; } = null!;

    public int PiecePerPallett { get; set; }

    public int Lotsize { get; set; }

    public int MoldPerDay { get; set; }

    public int FormAmount { get; set; }

    public int CavityAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal FormTime { get; set; }

    public decimal FillTime { get; set; }

    public decimal CarouselRotation { get; set; }

    public decimal CompletionTime { get; set; }

    public decimal Cycle { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously it doesn't work as I get an InvalidOperationException, but I mean, I do load all data beforehand and save it as a list, so why can't I retrieve / compare data from, for example "spewePoList"?

It would be nice to get some thoughts on this, and I thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Do not post code as images, image's text cannot be copied or searched.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Oh sry, I'll change it right away.

Comment: `I've got two dbcontexts, to get data from various tables` that's a terminal bug - as in, there's no way to fix it. DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work, not a database connection like SqlConnection, or a collection of tables. Although, you wouldn't be able to create JOINs even if it *was* a connection. DbContext itself creates JOINs when it has to based on the relations between entities. If you write `ctx.Customer.Where(c=>c.Id=23).Select(c=>new {c.Name,Orders=c.Orders.ToList()});`, DbContext will create the JOINs between Customers and Orders

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Describe the original problem, not what you think the solution looks like. `NAV_FS_DBContext` is suspicious and suggests you're trying to combine data from a Navision database with your own database, probably on a separate server. You can't create cross-server JOINs in the first place. ORMs like EF try to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows, they can't change how the database works. You *can* load objects (not rows) from different databases and work with them on the client but you can't combine the queries

Comment: The code has other critical problems too. `_navContext.SpeweSalesLines.ToListAsync();` and similar lines load the entire table in memory. If the table has 100K sales lines, all 100K will be loaded in memory. And while that very slow query runs, other application instances won't be able to modify the table - you'll block sales for everyone when you only really need sales lines for a single order

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Basically I just need some data from Navision to store it in a Model, so that I can display it in the View. I know it's not the best thing to load an entire table in memory, because as you said it would firstly take forever, and secondly I'll block the table on the server. I'm just trying it out in a small database, to see if this works, but I guess for a productive site, my "solution" would be stupid. I'm not entirely sure how to join multiple tables, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: @GogoDev, we can simplify this, but show your `NAV_FS_DBContext` classes used in this query, I'm interested in navigation properties.

Comment: Looks like you have stripped out navigation properties. You can remove other properties, but not navigation properties. It helps to create LINQ query.

Comment: Indeed, if the navigation properties were still there, the query would be almost trivial: `ShipmentDate = x.ShipmentDate, Priority = x.Priority`. No extra JOINS required. `Variables` looks like reference data that could be loaded in advance and even cached

Comment: So basically Navigation Properties are the solution. I guess I gotta add them then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### IEnumerable vs IQueryable

You have to be aware of the difference between an `IEnumerable` and an `IQueryable`.

An IEnumerable represents a sequence of similar items. You can ask for the first element of the sequence, and as long as you've got an element of the sequence you can ask for the next element of the sequence, until no more elements are left. The IEnumerable holds everything to fetch the elements of the sequence.

An IQueryable seems like an IEnumerable, however, it does not represent an Enumerable sequence, it represents *the potential to create an Enumerable sequence*.

For this, the IQueryable holds an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The Expression holds in some generic format what must be fetched, the Provider knows where the data will be fetched (usually a Database Management System), and what language is used to communicate with this DBMS (usually something like SQL).

The IQueryable also implements IEnumerable. When you ask the IQueryable to `GetEnumerator`, the Expression is sent to the Provider, who will translate the Expression into SQL, and execute the query. The fetched data is represented as an IEnumerable, of which GetEnumerator is called. Some smart Providers will only fetch data when the first element is enumerated.

**But what does this have to do with my question?**

Your two DbContexts represent two different database management systems. A DBMS is extremely optimized to combine tables and to select data from the result. The slower part of a query is the transport of the selected data from the DBMS to your local process. Hence it is wise to limit the amount of data being transferred.

By using `await ...ToListAsync()` you fetch a data from `_navContext` to your local process. Similarly you fetch some data from `_baseDataContext` to your local process.

Your final query sends all the fetched data from your local process to the `_navContext` database to execute your `Select` and `Where`. The selected records are then sent back from the DBMS to your local process. Although this will probably give you the required results, it is not very efficient.

It would be way more efficient to only fetch the data from `_baseDataContext`, then send the selected data to the `_navContext` DBMS, which will combine this data with data from tables `SpeweSalesLines`, `SpeweProdOrderLines`, and `SpeweProductionOrder` to create the required result.

Advantages are:

- you don't send the complete contents of tables `SpeweSalesLines`, and `SpeweProdOrderLines` to your local process, nor return this data to `_navContext` DBMS.
- only the data that you plan to use will be fetched from `_navContext`.

The improved query would be (in small steps):

The following won't execute the query, it will only *create* the query.
There is no communication with _navContext, no data will be selected.

```
IQueryable<SpeweSalesLine> sales = _navContext.SpeweSalesLines;
IQueryable<SpeweProdOrderLine> prodOrders = _navContext.SpeweProdOrderLines;
```

The query below will be executed. Data will be transferred from _baseDataContext
to your local process:

```
List<Variable> baseDataVariables = await _baseDataContext.Variables.ToListAsync();
```

Use the fetched data, and use the other two queries to create a new query. Again there is no communication with _navContext yet.

```
IQueryable<PoItemViewModel> poItemQuery = _navContext.SpeweProductionOrder
    .Select(x => new PoItemViewModel
    {
        Status = x.Status,
        PONr = x.No,
        ItemNr = x.SourceNo,
        FormType = x.Description,
        Quantity = x.Quantity,
        StartingDate = x.StartingDate,
        EndingDate = x.EndingDate,

        // Select the first ShipmentDate from the spewSales
        // that has a value for No that equals this x.No
        ShipmentDate = sales
           .Where(sale => sale.No == x.No)
           .Select(sale => sale.ShipmentDate)
           .FirstOrDefault(),

        // Select the first Priority from the speweProdOrders
        // that has a value for 
        Priority = speweProdOrders
            .Where(prodOrder => prodOrder.ProdOrderNo == x.No)
            .Select(prodOrder => prodOrder.Priority)
            .FirstOrDefault(),

        // Select the first MoldPerDay from the baseDataVariables that was fetched
        // from the _baseDataContext that has a SourceNo that equals this SourceNo
        Molds = baseDataList
            .Where(baseDataVariable => baseDataValues.SourceNo == x.SourceNo)
            .Select(baseDataVariable => baseDataVariable.MoldPerDay)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
        });
```

Now execute the query to create the desired result. The fetched baseDataVariables are sent to DBMS _navContext. The necessary tables are combined and the requested data is selected. Finally only the selected data will be sent to the local process:

```
List<<PoItemViewModel> poItems = await poItemQuery.ToListAsync().
```

Result:

- only the data that you use will be transferred from _baseDataContext to your local process, and then to _navContext.
- SpeweSalesLines and SpeweOrderLines are not transferred to your local process.
- Only the data that you plan to use is transferred from _navContext to your local process.

Of course, if desired you can put this all together in one big LINQ statement. It won't improve efficiency, however I'm sure it will deteriorate readability.

Answer (score 1):

At first, remove not needed meterialization of `speweSalesList` and `spewePoList`. All what we can do with single context, we should reuse.

Prepared example how to do that without navigation properties. It would be simplier and error prone to use navigation properties instead of explicit subqueries.

```cs
var baseDataList = await _baseDataContext.Variables
    .Select(v => new { v.SourceNo, v.MoldPerDay } )
    .ToListAsync();

// Just IQueryable shortucts
var speweSalesList = _navContext.SpeweSalesLines;
var spewePoList = _navContext.SpeweProdOrderLines;

var poItems = await _navContext.SpeweProductionOrder
    .Select(x => new PoItemViewModel
    {
        Status = x.Status,
        PONr = x.No,
        ItemNr = x.SourceNo,
        FormType = x.Description,
        Quantity = x.Quantity,
        StartingDate = x.StartingDate,
        EndingDate = x.EndingDate,
        ShipmentDate = speweSalesList.Where(y => y.No == x.No).Select(y => y.ShipmentDate).FirstOrDefault(),
        Priority = spewePoList.Where(y => y.ProdOrderNo == x.No).Select(y => y.Priority).FirstOrDefault(),
        Molds = baseDataList.Where(y => y.SourceNo == x.SourceNo).Select(y => y.MoldPerDay).FirstOrDefault()
    }).ToListAsync();
```

Please check that it works, `Molds` can be problematic and may need post postprocessing.
Also review your business logic, you are loading whole tables into the memory.

Comment: I suspect `await _navContext.SpeweSalesLines` should be `_navContext.SpeweSalesLines.AsQueryable()` but the resulting N queries generated by `speweSalesList.Where(y => y.No == x.No).Select(y => y.ShipmentDate)` and another N by ` baseDataList.Where` will be very slow. It would be better to retrieve the orders first, extract the order numbers, then load the separate parts into a dictionary by OrderNo with `orderNumbers.Oontains(y.No)`. That would require only 4 queries

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, corrected typos. Verys slow can be `Molds`, so probably client Dictionaty can be needed. Other can be slow if there are no indexes. Please give me chance to finish this answer. I'm also good in databases.

Comment: I know you are, which is why I knew that was a typo. I don't know if the root problem can be solved with a single answer though - the OP rushed to use an ORM without understanding SQL or databases. Like rushing to drive a Tesla without knowing how to drive. Something we keep seeing over and over lately.